# Time series function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

I am working with data that stops in a specific year and is NA afterwards. And I need to calculate allot of variables based on lagged values of other variables. I would like to find a way that a whole series is calculated instead of each time one year when one of the variables is NA. I was looking at dplyr given that I am working with panel data and thus need to group it by ID.

I provide the example below:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( year = c(seq(2000, 2018), seq(2000, 2018)) , id = c(rep(1, 19),rep(2, 19)), varA = floor(rnorm(38)*100), varB= floor(rnorm(38)*100), varC= floor(rnorm(38)*100))

df <- df %>% mutate(varA = if_else(year>2010, as.double(NA) , varA) , 
                    varB = if_else(year>2010, as.double(NA) , varB),
                    varC = if_else(year>2010, as.double(NA) , varC))  %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(year)
```

What I would like is to find a way to calculate a variable that is equal to variable C when it is available, but afterwards is equal to a formula based on lagged values of variable C, B and A. When executing the code below, varResult and D are ony calculated for one year given that the lags are only available for one year:

```
df <- df %>% mutate( varD = lag(varA)*lag(varB), 
                     varRESULT = if_else(is.na(varC), lag(varC, 1)/lag(varD, 2)*lag(varD, 1), varC))
```

But I would like to find a way to calculate immidiatly the whole serries  (taking into account the panel dimension of the data) instead of heaving to repeat the code 7 times. Preferably a solution where you can calculate varD seperatly from varResults, given that  in the final application I have multiple variables that are linked to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution:

Starting with the first `NA`, the "recursive" `lags` of vars `varA`, `varB`, and `varC` are equal to the last value of these variables.

Thus, starting from these initial variables, we can create new variables: `varA1`, `varB1`, and `varC1` where we fill the `NA`s with the last value, by `id`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # for the function `fill`

df <- df %>% 
mutate(varA1 = varA, varB1 = varB, varC1 = varC) %>% 
group_by(id) %>%
arrange(year) %>%
fill(varA1, varB1, varC1) # fills with last value
```

Then, we apply the formula:

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate( varD = lag(varA1)*lag(varB1), 
varRESULT = if_else(is.na(varC), lag(varC1, 1)/lag(varD, 2)*lag(varD, 1), varC)) %>% 
select(-varA1, -varB1, -varC1)
```